# Using extended color bar with logscale on pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contourf

In the following example (modified from [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/contourf_log.html)) I get an error regarding the use of the `extended` keyword when using a log scale:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import ma
from matplotlib import colors, ticker, cm
from matplotlib.mlab import bivariate_normal
N = 100
x = np.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, N)
y = np.linspace(-2.0, 2.0, N)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = (bivariate_normal(X, Y, 0.1, 0.2, 1.0, 1.0)
     + 0.1 * bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
cs = plt.contourf(X, Y, z, locator=ticker.LogLocator(), cmap=cm.PuBu_r, extend='both')
cbar = plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I have tried this in versions `1.5.3` and `1.5.1` and the exact error is

> ValueError: extend kwarg does not work yet with log scale

This is even said in that page so this is no surprise.

I have tried some workarounds to that, such as `cs.cmap.colorbar_extend = True`, but, although I get no error, the extended option isn't implemented.

Is there a workaround for this? In other words: can I implement a log scale on `contourf` even though the keyword isn't implemented yet?

Thank you.

Comment: When running your code I get a `ValueError: extend kwarg does not work yet with log  scale`, which is pretty self-explanatory. So you cannot use `extend` on a log scale. Is the question how to implement the `extend` keyword even though it is not implemented?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, that is what I meant. Was that not clear? I'll try to make it clearer.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Edited, sorry it wasn't clear